# Displaying a Video in REACT.js that replays

Tags: reactjs, rxjs, clone, video-component

I am making a clone of a website using React. I am fairly new to React js and am trying to add a video that replays on its own. If anyone can at least point me in the right direction of documentation, I would appreciate it.

I do not want the video to take up the whole screen. I believe the video should be its own component, i think.

The website I am cloning is halfsumo.com [see the video below the nav bar section.](https://halfsumo.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Attribute `loop` on `<video/>` element should do the job.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.